# How do I create a SQL Function to return a BIT?

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions

I am using this script below to create a function but I get an error in the messages log:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction] () RETURNS BIT AS RETURN CAST(1 AS BIT)
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure MyFunction, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'RETURN'.

It works when I change this to return a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction] () RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (SELECT 1 [1])
```

so I am not sure what is wrong. Why does this work for a table but not a bit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your syntax to include a begin and end like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction]()
RETURNS bit 
AS 
begin 
RETURN CAST(1 AS bit) 
end
```

Comment: That worked thanks. Could you elaborate on why it worked for a table but not the bit? That might help other people in the future. Thanks again - I will accept your answer when the time limit has elapsed.

Comment: @Avitus Your Table example is a special kind of UDF(user-defined function) called an "*Inline Table-Valued function*". They have a different definition format compared to Multi-line Table-Valued functions and to scalar functions like this (which are always multi-line).

Answer (score 0):

For a more real life example than just returning a bit value in the accepted answer, here is useful code to check against another table and return a bit

```
return case when exists (select 1 from Ref.Detail RD
                        where RD.DetailId = @statusDetailId
                        and RD.DetailFlagId = -3)
                        -- -3 is Canceled
            then 1 else 0 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy, paste and change as nedded.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FUNCTION_NAME (@Param1 char(10))
RETURNS Bit
AS
BEGIN
    Return Case 
        When Exists (Select 1 FROM schema.tableName
                     Where column1 = @Param1)
            Then 1 Else 0
        End;
END
GO
```

Comment: I tried this and got back "Incorrect syntax near 'End'."

Comment: Be sure to rename:
-dbo.FUNCTION_NAME with your custom name
-schema.tableName with your table name
-column1 with your column name

Let us know if you resolved

Comment: That's what I did.