# Stored procedure return as IF condition boolean expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What's the best way to use a stored procedure (or function) return as the condition in an IF statement?

Something that will allow me to do something close to this, having declared a procedure/function 'CheckCondition' that returns true/false 1/0 value either with a CAST or as an output

```
IF CheckCondition 1, 'asfa' 
BEGIN
    //do something
ELSE
    //do something else
END
```

The function/procedure doesn't need to do INSERT or UPDATE, only SELECT, so I guess a function would do.

Thanks

Comment: For how to use a Stored Procedure for this, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965764/1220550. A user defined function might however be more intuitive: `IF fn_CheckCondition(1, 'asfa') = 1 BEGIN ...` Note that in T-SQL, boolean variables do not exist so you'd have to use a BIT or INT.

Comment: @PeterB anything special in the function declaration? how does it return the value? `return 1` would work?

Comment: I would suggest to use the BIT data type and return either 0 or 1 ...

Comment: Yes, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17028961/1220550

Answer (score 0):

Stored Proc with an output parameter a solution;

```
create proc dbo.Condition

@Result bit output

as

set nocount on

set @Result=0 -- assumes false . . .

if 1=1 -- i.e. this is TRUE
    begin
        set @Result=1
    end
go
declare @Result bit

exec dbo.Condition
    @Result=@Result output

print @Result -- here's the result
```

Example above creates a proc and the bit at the buttom is how to execute it and get the result

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, finally did like this, with function instead of procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckCondition]
(
    @Parameter1 int = 0,
    @Parameter2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 0,
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN   
    IF ( boolean expression with selects )          
        RETURN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE
        RETURN CAST(0 AS bit)
    RETURN CAST(0 AS bit)
END
```

Use it like this:

```
IF dbo.CheckCondition(@param1, 'sdasf') = 1
     //Do something
ELSE
     //Do something else
```

Thanks everyone!